# Why are Google Analytics cookies appearing in ELMAH log?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, google-analytics, elmah

I'm using Firefox 45.0.1 for testing my ASP.NET MVC web application. ELMAH shows following HTTP cookies being sent: __qca, __utma, __utmz, _ga, __utmb, __utmt

- The only JS I'm using is modernizr, jQuery and bootstrap.
- I'm not using Google Analytics in my application.
- The only search engines in my Firefox are Wikipedia and Stackoverflow.
- **EDIT:** Do not have Google Toolbar installed in Firefox

**Where are these cookies coming from?**

Are they appearing because of some Firefox extension I've installed? Or are they appearing because I'm signed into Google in another tab (how can that happen??) ?

Comment: Are you using any extensions for Firefox? Could be Google Toolbar as well.

Comment: Was it Google Toolbar?